# Issues with using oh-my-zsh on WSL Bash (on Windows using Ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am having issues running executables such as terraform, docker, pip, and sam. Whenever I run in the command line I receive an error for each of these executables:  "Command  not found". However, if I am to run python, git, or npm, they work! The only way for me to run the executables is to apply ".exe" of the ones not working. Mind you I am working on Windows OS using WSL (using Ubuntu). Could the issue be with the path of these executables in ~/.zshrc? I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to ohmyzsh or zsh, but as you said, related to working in WSL.

I would suggest installing applications directly in the WSL where possible. Docker for Windows has good integration when using WSL2 (follow the breadcrumbs [here](https://aka.ms/wsl2) to update to WSL2).

There are two methods to use Windows binaries (.exe files) in WSL:

1. by creating symbolic links within WSL to a directory that is in your PATH

   ex: `ln -s $(which terraform.exe) ~/.local/bin/terraform`
2. by creating symbolic links in Windows

   1. You probably need to make a new folder and add it to your PATH (see [this guide](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)).
   2. Then, open an admin `cmd` and cd to this new folder
   3. Lastly, do `mklink terraform "C:\Program Files\Terraform\terraform.exe"` or wherever  terraform.exe resides

[Additional info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#command-not-found-when-executing-windows-exe-in-linux)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line to yout `.zshrc` file

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: It doesn't work for me.